# Can text be extracted from Robot framework screenshot?

Tags: python, selenium, text, robotframework, extract

Is it possible to extract text from Screenshots from the robot framework?
We will run a robot framework for a month to take a screenshot of our administration website per hour.
There is some information(text) and I want to extract the information as text and evaluate in Excel.
The output from actually doesn't matter.

Is it possible?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The information you need as text **should be retrieved as text** by getting the text/value of selected web elements on the page. Or is there any problem with such approach?

Comment: If you're running robot, why not scrape the data from the website before taking the screenshot?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use the screenshots as a source for text? The added complexity of doing the image-to-text conversion seems to weigh much higher, without any additional benefit, from taking the screenshot, logging the HTML source and any piece of text you may be specifically interested in.

Comment: @A.Kootstra thanks for comment. I decided to evaluate the data from screenshot in excel after i got many screenshots. The previous data i can't see anymore in web. Our admin website shows the data only that time when you log in which means i have the previous data only as screenshot. That's the reason.

Comment: Which means that going forward you will store all the infromation so that you can compare in the future. This means determining if the current situation can be the golden master to compare against in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can with robot framework, but you can try this with python to read images:
https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

This is a wrapper for https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract developed by Google. It may fit your needs.

I don't know if you will have to use it with OpenCV, seems not.